# EF Sum nested list values after group by

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

So I have a list of tickets, I want to group them by customer and then sum all the **prices** of the ticket operations of these tickets.

```
            query2 = query.GroupBy(x => new {x.Customer.Id, x.Customer.BusinessName}).Select(x => new TicketStatisticsRow {
                Field = x.Key.BusinessName,
                Tickets = x.Count(),
                TotalPrice = x.Sum(t => t.TicketOperations.Sum(to => to.Price))
            });
```

Other than trying the sum of the sum for **TotalPrice** i tried `x.SelectMany(e => e.TicketOperations).Sum(x=> x.Price)` both these solutions cannot be **evaluated locally**.. What could be the best approach in this situation?

For reference the ticket class:

```
 public class Ticket {
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TicketOperation> TicketOperations { get; set; }

        public class TicketOperation {
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this

```
query2 = query.GroupBy(x=>x.Customer.Id).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=> new 
         TicketStatisticsRow {
            Field = x.Key.BusinessName,
            Tickets = x.Count(),
            TotalPrice = x.Sum(t => t.TicketOperations.Sum(to => to.Price))
        });
```